# Default types for 'complex' in C

Tags: c, gcc

According the docs I have read C99 and later support `float complex`, `double complex` and `long double complex` as complex types. However this code compiles without warning when using `gcc -Wall -Wextra`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    float re, im;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    complex matrix[a][b]; /* <------ */

    for(c=0; c<a; c++) {
        for(d=0; d<b; d++) {
            scanf("%f%fi", &re, &im);
            matrix[c][d] = re + im * I;
        }
    }

    for(c=0; c<a; c++) {
        for(d=0; d<b; d++) {
            printf("%.2f%+.2fi ", creal(matrix[c][d]), cimag(matrix[c][d]));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

- Is this valid C or is it a gcc oddity?
- What type is `complex matrix[a][b];` giving us?

---

If you compile it with clang you get:

> main.c:9:5: warning: plain '_Complex' requires a type specifier;
>   assuming '_Complex double'

See the [clang output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63e8caf872c0611e).

---

gcc bug now reported at [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79084). (Not by me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like both GCC and Clang assume the type to be `double` if you omit it (like in your example).
Clang produces:

```
 warning: plain '_Complex' requires a type specifier; assuming '_Complex double'
    complex matrix[a][b];
    ^
            double
/usr/include/complex.h:39:18: note: expanded from macro 'complex'
#define complex         _Complex
                        ^
```

While does GCC does the same (assuming `double`), it doesn't seem to warn it.

Regardless of compiler diagnostics, `complex` which expands to `_Complex` is not a *type* by itself but only a *type specifier*. So, you need to specify the type.

Comment: Thanks. How can you tell gcc assumes double?

Comment: By using GCC's [typeof](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html).

Comment: Looks like a bug in gcc in that case.  Thanks so much.

Comment: `double` is also a *type specifier*.

Comment: Turns out `gcc -Wsystem-headers -Wpedantic readcomplex.c`  gives a warning. This still looks like a gcc bug to me though.

Answer (score 5):

According to C99 (ISO 9899:1999):

- `complex` is a macro (defined in `<complex.h>`) that expands to `_Complex` (7.3.1/2).
- `_Complex` is a type specifier (just like `int`, `double`, `unsigned`, etc) (6.7.2/1).

6.7.2/2:

> **Constraints**
>
> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration, and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. Each list of type specifiers shall be one of the following sets (delimited by commas, when there is more than one set on a line); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.
>
> - [...]
> - `float _Complex`
> - `double _Complex`
> - `long double _Complex`

These are the only type specifier sets that contain `_Complex`, which means that `complex` without `float`, `double`, or `long double` is not allowed.

Furthermore:

> **5.1.1.3 Diagnostics**
>
> 1 A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
>   specified as undefined or implementation-defined.

Since using `complex` all by itself is a constraint violation, a compiler warning or error is required. If you don't get a warning with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic`, then you've found a bug in gcc.

Comment: You get a warning using `gcc -Wsystem-headers -Wpedantic readcomplex.c`.   The "complex" macro is defined in a system header, so gcc thinks diagnostics relating to it should be hidden ... which is dumb.

Comment: @eleanora Yeah, that definitely looks like a bug to me.