# Wrong 2D CuFFT inverse transform compared to fftw3

Tags: c++, cuda, fftw, cufft

I'm trying to produce some FFT math, in particular it's do two 2D forward transforms, multiply them, and then make  inverse transform. Before inverse transform everything goes great. I've already did it by fftw3, but in CuFFT something goes wrong. Most of the values are similar, but some are wrong, which is significant for the future math. What's the problem with this piece of code?

```
std::vector<complex> conv2dCUDA(complex *ui_anomaly, double *ds2, 
complex *u0, int anx, int any, double factor) {
    cufftComplex *b1, *b2;
    int size = 2 * anx * 2 * any;
    int memsize = size *  sizeof(cufftComplex);
    b1 = (cufftComplex *)calloc(size, sizeof(cufftComplex));
    b2 = (cufftComplex *)calloc(size, sizeof(cufftComplex));

    // filling the matrixes    

    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftComplex *ui, *g;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&ui, memsize));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&g,  memsize));
    checkCudaErrors(cufftPlan2d(&plan, 2 * anx, 2 * any, CUFFT_C2C));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(ui, (cufftComplex *)&b1[0], memsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(g, (cufftComplex *)&b2[0], memsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    checkCudaErrors(cufftExecC2C(plan, ui, ui, CUFFT_FORWARD));
    checkCudaErrors(cufftExecC2C(plan, g, g, CUFFT_FORWARD));
    int blockSize = 16;
    dim3 dimGrid(int(2 * any / blockSize) + 1, int(2 * anx / blockSize) + 1);
    dim3 dimBlock(blockSize, blockSize);

    ComplexMulAndScale<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(ui, g, size, 1.0f);
    getLastCudaError("Kernel execution went wrong");

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(b1, ui, memsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    std::cout << "After mult Cuda" << std::endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 2 * any; i++) {
       for (auto j = 0; j < 2 * anx; j++) {
            std::cout << b1[i * 2 * anx + j].x << " ";
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    checkCudaErrors(cufftExecC2C(plan, ui, ui, CUFFT_INVERSE));
    cuComplex *inversed;
    inversed = (cuComplex*)malloc(memsize);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(inversed, ui, memsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    std::vector<complex> res(anx * any);
    for (auto i = 0; i < any; i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < anx; j++) {
            res[i * anx + j] = complex(inversed[i * anx * 2 + j].x * factor, inversed[i * anx * 2 + j].y * factor);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "CUDA"  << std::endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 2 * any; i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 2 * anx; j++) {
            std::cout << inversed[i * 2 * anx + j].x << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(ui));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(g));
    checkCudaErrors(cufftDestroy(plan));
    free(b1);
    free(b2);
    free(inversed);
    return res;
}

std::vector<complex> conv2d(complex *ui_anomaly, double *ds2, complex *u0, int anx, int any, double factor) {
    std::vector<complex> b1(anx * 2 * 2 * any, complex(0., 0.)), b2(anx * 2 * 2 * any, complex(0., 0.));

    // filling matrixes

    // forward fft 1 in-place
    fftw_plan p;
    p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(2 * any, 2 * anx, (fftw_complex *) (&b1[0]), (fftw_complex *) (&b1[0]),
                     FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    // forward fft 2 in-place
    p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(2 * any, 2 * anx, (fftw_complex *) (&b2[0]), (fftw_complex *) (&b2[0]),
                     FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    std::vector<complex> out(2 * anx * 2 * any, complex(0., 0.));

    for (auto i = 0; i < 2 * any * 2 * anx; i++) {
        out[i] = b1[i] * b2[i];
    }
    std::cout << "After mult fftw" << std::endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 2 * any; i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 2 * anx; j++) {
            std::cout << out[i * 2 * anx + j].real() << " ";
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    // inverse fft in-place
    p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(2 * (int) any, 2 * (int) anx, (fftw_complex *) (&out[0]), (fftw_complex *) (&out[0]),FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);

    std::vector<complex> res(anx * any);
    for (auto i = 0; i < any; i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < anx; j++) {
            res[i * anx + j] = out[i * anx * 2 + j] * factor;
       }
    }
    std::cout << "FFTW" << std::endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 2 * any; i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 2 * anx; j++) {
            std::cout << out[i * 2 * anx + j].real() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return res;
}
```

So, this is my code. Output should be in both functions

```
After mult fftw
8.34304e-08 -5.99259e-07 -4.7876e-07 5.30254e-07 9.55877e-07 4.28985e-07 
-1.56375e-07 1.19699e-07 2.39276e-07 -1.68662e-08 -7.56988e-08 -3.69897e-07 
-2.66505e-07 -2.33361e-07 -5.21763e-07 -5.29126e-07 1.8915e-07 1.68158e-07 
-9.01859e-07 -2.37453e-07 -3.50661e-08 -4.11154e-07 4.14802e-07 -7.9879e-07 
2.09404e-07 6.52034e-08 1.8915e-07 4.97805e-07 3.32612e-07 -2.33361e-07 
-1.95738e-07 -3.69897e-07 -1.63577e-07 1.07737e-07 2.39276e-07 2.50198e-07 
FFTW
-1.57349e-06 -7.5964e-06 -1.57349e-06 1.68876e-06 5.82335e-22 1.68876e-06 
2.37158e-06 6.35275e-22 2.37158e-06 -1.18579e-06 1.05879e-22 -1.18579e-06 
-1.57349e-06 -7.5964e-06 -1.57349e-06 1.68876e-06 1.97573e-22 1.68876e-06 
3.14928e-06 2.37158e-06 3.14928e-06 -4.94164e-07 5.82335e-22 -4.94164e-07 
2.11758e-22 -8.47033e-22 -1.05879e-22 5.29396e-22 1.41851e-23 1.05879e-22 
3.14928e-06 2.37158e-06 3.14928e-06 -4.94164e-07 1.05879e-22 -4.94164e-07 

After mult Cuda
8.34303e-08 -5.99259e-07 -4.78761e-07 5.30254e-07 9.55877e-07 4.28985e-07 
-1.56375e-07 1.19699e-07 2.39276e-07 -1.68662e-08 -7.56988e-08 -3.69897e-07 
-2.66505e-07 -2.33361e-07 -5.21763e-07 -5.29126e-07 1.8915e-07 1.68158e-07 
-9.01859e-07 -2.37453e-07 -3.50661e-08 -4.11154e-07 4.14802e-07 -7.9879e-07 
2.09404e-07 6.52034e-08 1.8915e-07 4.97805e-07 3.32612e-07 -2.33361e-07 
-1.95738e-07 -3.69897e-07 -1.63577e-07 1.07737e-07 2.39276e-07 2.50198e-07 
CUDA
-1.57349e-06 -7.5964e-06 -1.57349e-06 1.68876e-06 3.33981e-13 1.68876e-06 
2.37158e-06 2.84217e-13 2.37158e-06 -1.18579e-06 1.10294e-13 -1.18579e-06 
-1.57349e-06 -7.5964e-06 -1.57349e-06 1.68876e-06 -9.03043e-14 1.68876e-06 
3.14928e-06 2.37158e-06 3.14928e-06 -4.94164e-07 4.62975e-13 -4.94164e-07 
-3.2685e-13 -1.03562e-13 -3.59548e-13 -2.13163e-13 4.27658e-15 -2.43358e-14 
3.14928e-06 2.37158e-06 3.14928e-06 -4.94164e-07 3.49288e-13 -4.94164e-07
```

As it can be seen, both forward fft and multiplication goes right, but in case of inverse fft by cuda smth went wrong.

P.S. Sorry for poor code style

Comment: How do you know fftw is the right one? Have you computed ft by hand?

Comment: @huseyin I've done it by hand and it was also tested on some examples

Comment: You've only printed the real values in the complex domain after the pointwise multiply and scale.  Perhaps your kernel code is broken, which you haven't shown.  Anyway you should provide a complete code, not just 2 functions.  Provide the data (there isn't that much of it) as well as a main routine that calls both functions.  Everything someone else needs to run your code.  That is called a [mcve], and SO expects it for questions like this, see item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This looks like a precision issue to me; the default fftw precision is 64-bit, whereas you're using the 32-bit variants of cufft. Try using cufftDoubleComplex (64-bit) instead of cufftComplex (32-bit), and read up on how to perform 64-bit cufft computations (iirc, cufftExecC2C becomes cufftExecZ2Z, there may be other changes as well). Edit: Just noticed that @francis has answered with a similar comment. I concur

Answer (score 1):

As FFTW is used, the convolved signal features a lot of numbers of about 1e-6 and a few numbers of about 1e-22. It is likely that it should have been zeros, but it is not since these zeros are computed using double precision floating point numbers. Double precision numbers are about 15 digits precise, so errors near 1e(-6-15)=1e-21 could occur.

As cufft is used, these figures that should have been zeros are about 1e-13, as if computations have been performed using single precision floating point number.
**It is the case: the types [`cuComplex`](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/cuComplex.html) and [`cufftComplex`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#cufftcomplex) are single precision complex, while [`fftw_complex`](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html) is a double precision complex**. While [`complex` likely defaults to double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638105/default-types-for-complex-in-c), it can be cleary specified as `double complex`.

To get figures near 1e-22, please try the types [`cufftDoubleComplex`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#cufftdoublecomplex) and [`cuDoubleComplex`](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/cuDoubleComplex.html). The `blockSize` introduced to perform many multiplications at once may need to be reduced to 8. However, while it is likely that figures of magnitude 1e-22 could be obtained, it is also likely that these figures still differ from those of FFTW. Indeed, since the algorithms could be different, different operations could have been performed and the precision is such that anything about 1e-22 in the outcome is not significantly different from 0.

Nevertheless, changing for double precision numbers may increase computation time and clearly increases the memory footprint. If a six-digit precision on the outcome of the convolution is good enough for your application, sticking to single precision complex DFT could be the right way to go.